# Using Jasmine spyOn to mock function in Browserify module

Tags: jasmine, browserify

I'm trying to run a unit test on a function (testFunc). testFunc calls another function (secondFunc) which I would like to mock. Can I mock secondFunc so that when it is called in the context of testFunc, the spiedOn version of secondFunc is called? If not, how should I reformat my browserify module to make it testable?

Currently the setup looks something like this:

app.js (Browserify Module)

```
module.exports = (function () {
    function testFunc() {
        secondFunc();
    }

    function secondFunc(){
        console.log('not mocked!');
    }

    return {
        testFunc, secondFunc
    };

})();
```

test.js (Jasmine Test)

```
describe("testFunc", () => {
    let app = require('./app');

    beforeEach(() => {
        spyOn(app, 'secondFunc');
    });

    it("should call secondFunc spy", () => {
        app.testFunc();
        expect(app.secondFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it now, the `spyOn` is replacing the `secondFunc` property on your returned object with a proxy, but your code calls the `secondFunc` function that is inside the closure of the anonymous function. There are several ways to restructure your code to better expose the functions.

You could structure your module this way:

```
exports.testFunc = function() {
    exports.secondFunc();
}

exports.secondFunc = function(){
    console.log('not mocked!');
}
```

which is a lot smaller, easier to read, and let you mock the `secondFunc` function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you are setting up a mock on the returned object, but the code is calling the internal function.  What I've done in the past is something like this:

```
module.exports = (function () {
    function testFunc() {
        api.secondFunc();   // Call the API function, which is what is mocked
    }

    function secondFunc(){
        console.log('not mocked!');
    }

    var api = {
        testFunc, secondFunc
    };

    return api;

})();
```